# Change a field to YesNo in Web Forms

Tags: visual-studio, webforms

I need to create a field in Web forms as a Yes/No field. However, on the web page it only takes values as 1,-1 or 0. How can i change this

Below is the code i am using and i want the StateID field to be a Yes/No field and the Card number field that can take a 16 digit value

```
Dim sSelectSQL As String = "CREATE TABLE Guests"
            sSelectSQL &= "([GuestID] Number, [LName] TEXT(20),"
            sSelectSQL &= "[FName] TEXT(20), [ZipCode] Number,"
            sSelectSQL &= "[StateID] YesNo, [CardNo] Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL there is no YE/NO field You need to set it a Bit (1 or 0)... Since i am new i am not able to comment, so just posting it as answer..
in dropdown you can replsent it as YES/NO or in actual 1 0r 0 replsents TRUE/FALSE state